# Checkout code tfs from comand line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I want to checkout the code from TFS from command line. I have integrated the TFS in eclipse and using java. I have found many answer in stackoverflow but every one saying about ...Common7\IDE\TF.exe and i am not using .net also in my visual studio 9.0 i did not find TF.exe.

Could you please help me in finding the way to checkout the code from command line when we are using eclipse and java. I don't have integrated maven or ant and not want to integrate it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has command line tools for TFS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx

Also there is a plugin for eclipse that gives you direct interface with TFS quite similar to how it is in Visual Studio.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tfs-plug-eclipse#.VCLNZHktCM8

Comment: i have already install plugin but i want to checkout from command line . Do we have to install visual studio for this even we are not using .net?

Comment: You don't need Visual Studio installed. You can install Team Explorer you just need the same version as your TFS instance. Here is a link to the 2010 version:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329

Answer (score 0):

You want [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx).

This includes the Eclipse plugin, but it also includes a java based command line for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: While the TEE command-line client will run fine on Windows, we would still recommend using the standalone Team Explorer is superior for Windows users.  It is significantly more feature rich on Windows.